# How Can we merge different events in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I'm trying to parse a log file into elasticsearch through logstash.
**My LogFile have different events that I want to merge together**(Each event have different pattern but some unique ID)
For e.g.

- Timestamp, loglevel, unique id, some Start Message , userName
- Timestamp, loglevel, unique id, some file
- Timestamp, loglevel, unique id, some count
- Timestamp, loglevel, unique id, Time taken By job

*I want to merge this events into one*
So I can understand Time taken by a job, what's the count and other things
Like my outcome should contains fields like

TimeStarted
loglevel
Start Message
UserName
Some File
count
TimeTakenBy Job

This is how I want to merge and store different events in the logs with the help of some unique ID which will be same OR unique for the events

Issue is I'm not able to understand how we can achieve this, **How can I merge this different pattern logs in a single document ??.**

**Any help is appreciable
Thank You!**

Answer (score 0):

You would use an aggregate filter to combine them. You can use dissect or grok to extract the fields. I would start with

```
dissect { mapping => { "message" => "%{[@metadata][ts]}", %{loglevel}, %{id}, %{[@metadata][restOfLine]} " } }
```

then use a date filter to parse [@metadata][ts] into [@timestamp]. Next, use grok to pick apart the [@metadata][restOfLine] field. In the aggregate filter you would use something similar to [example 3](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html#plugins-filters-aggregate-example3) in the documentation. When you use the push_map_as_event_on_timeout option only those fields you have added to the map are part of the event. So you would add fields to the map as you see each line. Something like

```
 aggregate {
     task_id => "%{id}"
     code => '
         map["id"] ||= event.get("id")
         map["@timestamp"] ||= event.get("@timestamp")
         map["loglevel"] ||= event.get("loglevel")
         map["username"] ||= event.get("username")
         map["timetaken"] ||= event.get("timetaken")
         # etc. etc.
         event.cancel # This delete the event that items were grok'd from.
     '
     push_map_as_event_on_timeout => true
     timeout => 10
 }
```

Note the limits in the aggregate documentation such as pipeline.workers 1 and having the right setting for pipeline.ordered.

Comment: Thanks @Badger  I'll try that out